# Webpack html-webpack-plugin is not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

When I run the command `npm run build`, I expect that `index.html` should be copied into `dist` as in this tutorial at 10:00:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw&t=602s

However nothing happens, no warning and no errors.
Here's the config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.export ={
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {minimize: true}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename:'./index.html'
        }),
    ],
}
```

Here's my complete code:
https://github.com/wickedrahul/webpackFourSetup

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out :)
You have a typo in webpack `module.exports` not `module.export`. And one more thing - `template: './src/index.html'` and `filename: index.html`

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Oops that typo indeed was the issue and I'm gonna loathe myself for not figuring that out even in the couple of hours that I wasted over :) `index.html` was alright though, it denotes the destination where it's gonna be copied to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Grzegorz T, it was a typo. Corrected `module.export` to `module.exports` to resolve the issue.